# Identifying with VBA the specific row of an Excel worksheet that contains a sub-string of text

Tags: excel, vba

At my work we get Excel files with multiple worksheets that are pulled from various data sources.  Some of the worksheets have a standardized disclaimer inserted at the end, some don't.  But when the disclaimers appear they always start with the same text and always appear in the same column.  I'm trying to write a VBA script that will search through an entire Excel file; determine if disclaimers are present, and if so, what row they start on; then clear all the cells from that row to the last used row.

As far as I can tell by hunting through StackOverflow and other resources, the code below should work.  But for some reason, it never actually identifies when the key sub-string is present (even when it is).  Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Option Base 1

Sub Delete_Disclaimers()

' Turn off screen updating for speed

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


' Define variables

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TextCheck As String
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim EndRow As Integer
Dim SearchColumn As Integer
Dim CheckVal As Integer
Dim CurrentCell As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim SearchText As String


' Cycle through each worksheet in the workbook
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


'Set some initial variables for this worksheet

SearchColumn = 2
StartRow = 1
SearchText = "Disclaimer"

' Set EndRow to the last row used in the worksheet
EndRow = CInt(ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)


' Find the cell, if any, that has the text by searching just in column B to speed things up.  Also limit to the first 200 rows
' for speed since there don't seem to have any sheets longer than that.    

For RowCount = 1 To 200
    Set CurrentCell = ws.Cells(2, RowCount)
    TextCheck = CurrentCell.Text
    If Not TextCheck = "" Then
        CheckVal = InStr(1, TextCheck, SearchText, 1)
        If CheckVal > 0 Then
            StartRow = RowCount
            MsgBox ("Start Row is " & CStr(StartRow))
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next RowCount


' If the search text was found, clear the range from the start row to the end row. 

If StartRow > 1 Then
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, StartRow), ws.Cells(50, EndRow)).Clear
End If



' Loops to next Worksheet
Next ws


' Turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


' Display a message box that all sheets have been cleared, now that screenupdating is back on
MsgBox "All Worksheets have been cleared!"


End Sub
```

Comment: [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you in the right track

Comment: Siddarth, thanks for the link.  I tried .Find before posting this and even after going back and modifying per your examples, I'm still getting no matches found.  Here is a snippet:  With ws.Range("b1:b200")
   Set CurrentCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=SearchText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

   If Not CurrentCell Is Nothing Then
        StartRow = CInt(CurrentCell.Row)
    End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for Cells is incorrect.  It should be Cells(row, col).  You have row and col transposed.

Comment: Thanks!  This definitely helped.

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up being a combination of both of the answers above.  But the .Clear section was definition a major problem I had overlooked.  Here is the full updated code in case it helps anyone else with similar problem.

```
Option Explicit

Option Base 1

Sub Delete_Portfolio_Holdings()

' Turn off screen updating for speed

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


' Define variables

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TextCheck As String
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim EndRow As Integer
Dim SearchColumn As Integer
Dim CheckVal As Integer
Dim CurrentCell As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim SearchText As String
Dim ClearRange As Range

Dim WScount As Integer
Dim cws As Integer


' Cycle through each worksheet in the workbook

WScount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For cws = 1 To WScount


'Set some initial variables for this worksheet

SearchColumn = 2
StartRow = 1
SearchText = "Disclaimer"
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(cws)

' Set EndRow to the last row used in the worksheet
EndRow = CInt(ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)


' Find the cell, if any, that has the text by searching just in column B to speed things up.  Also limit to the first 200 rows
' for speed since you don't seem to have any sheets longer than that.  You can always change to increase if necessary.  Cells.Find
' does not return anything if there is no match for the text, so CurrentRow may not change.

With ws.Range("b1:b200")
   Set CurrentCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=SearchText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
   If Not CurrentCell Is Nothing Then
        StartRow = CInt(CurrentCell.Row)
   End If
End With


' Now if the text was found we now have identified the start and end rows of the caveats, we can clear columns A through BB with the .Clear function.  Choice of column BB is arbitary.

If StartRow > 1 Then
    Set ClearRange = ws.Range(("A" & StartRow), ("BB" & EndRow))
    MsgBox ("ClearRange is " & CStr(ClearRange.Address))
    ClearRange.Clear
End If



' Loops to next Worksheet
Next cws


' Turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


' Display a message box that all sheets have been cleared, now that screenupdating is back on
MsgBox "All Worksheets have been cleared!"


End Sub
```

Comment: Correct language code for your code block would be `vb` or nothing and not `lang-html` as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting and also don't use the `snippet` tag as your code block is not really executable in a browser. You can/should use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26812073/edit) button to fix it

Comment: If you are interested I can post a solution on how to use `.Find` in your case...

Comment: I used .Find in the Answer.  If you have an alternate method, feel free to add it.  I for one would be interested in learning about any alternate options.